# Counting lines of text after a specific word

Tags: excel-formula

I need to find out how many lines a character has in a play using Excel. The entire play is copied into one column in excel and I need to find out how many spoken lines a specific character has. When a character speaks, their name is listed in bold and all caps, followed by a blank cell then all of the lines they are speaking until another character speaks. At the end of their lines is another blank cell. So for example it would look like this:

```
1st CHARACTER
(Blank Cell)
"Line"
"Line"
"Line"
(Blank Cell)
2nd CHARACTER
```

I need a formula to count how many lines occur for the first character, but one that can be repeated for the entire play. Any ideas even if its just a preliminary formula would be greatly appreciated.

I have tried using COUNTIF, OFFSET, INDEX/MATCH and I just can not find the right combination to get the correct output and then apply that to the whole play.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide the code you have tried so far and what bit did not work exactly with your code. Maybe have a look at [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to create a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Is VBA an option?

Comment: Unfortunately I can not use VBA in this case, otherwise I think that would definitely be the easiest solution to the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Count lines of text after a specific word/character

Assume data housed in Column A with criteria in Column C

In `D2`, formula copied down :

```
=SUM(AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(INDEX($A$1:$A$100,MATCH(C2,$A$1:$A$100,0)):$A$100)/(INDEX($A$1:$A$100,MATCH(C2,$A$1:$A$100,0)):$A$100=""),{1,2})*{-1,1})-1
```

[image]